# Breaking up a large XML file

Tags: xml

I have a large XML file (see bellow) as you can see I have two sections, the full document is around 7 sections and about 30 questions each so its a large XML file.

I would like to have one file with includes that pull the files in order, for example at the end of one file the next starts

**exam.xml**

```
include exam1.xml;
include exam2.xml;
include exam3.xml;
```

and have exam1 read first then 2 then 3, Is this posible in xml and how ?

**My large XML file**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <row test_type="1" timelimit_minutes="30" banner="images/banner.jpg" solutionURL="Test4-Solutions.pdf" maxMinutes="5" minPercentTime="30" resultsImage="images/pixel.gif" resultsURL="http://www.somne.co.uk/ss/ss.php">
            <intro><![CDATA[
                <h1>dd Arguments 1</h1>
        <p style="font-family: Georgia">
       some intro text.
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: Georgia">
       more test
        </p>
        <p style="font-family: Georgia">
       more ...
        <p style="font-family: Georgia">
      last bit
        </p>]]>

            </intro>
            <questions>
                <question>
                    <question_text>Yes; some text.</question_text>
                    <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
                    <distactors>
                        <distractor type="1">correct</distractor>
                        <distractor>incorrect</distractor>
                    </distactors>
                </question>
                <question>
                    <question_text>No; wrong.</question_text>
                    <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
                    <distactors>
                        <distractor>correct</distractor>
                        <distractor type="1">wrong</distractor>
                    </distactors>
                </question>
</row>
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <row test_type="1" timelimit_minutes="30" banner="images/banner.jpg" solutionURL="Test4-Solutions.pdf" maxMinutes="5" minPercentTime="30" resultsImage="images/pixel.gif" resultsURL="http://www.somne.co.uk/ss/ss.php">
                <intro><![CDATA[
                    <h1>dd Arguments 1</h1>
            <p style="font-family: Georgia">
           some intro text.
            </p>
            <p style="font-family: Georgia">
           more test
            </p>
            <p style="font-family: Georgia">
           more ...
            <p style="font-family: Georgia">
          last bit
            </p>]]>

                </intro>
                <questions>
                    <question>
                        <question_text>Yes; some text.</question_text>
                        <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
                        <distactors>
                            <distractor type="1">correct</distractor>
                            <distractor>incorrect</distractor>
                        </distactors>
                    </question>
                    <question>
                        <question_text>No; wrong.</question_text>
                        <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
                        <distactors>
                            <distractor>correct</distractor>
                            <distractor type="1">wrong</distractor>
                        </distactors>
                    </question>
    </row>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment, I have used xInclude, however my included file dose not seem to load. Please see bellow.

**exam.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<row test_type="1" timelimit_minutes="30" banner="images/banner.jpg" solutionURL="Test4-Solutions.pdf" maxMinutes="5"
     minPercentTime="30" resultsImage="images/pixel.gif" resultsURL="http://www.some.co.uk/ss/ss.php">

    <intro>
        <![CDATA[
        <h1>header</h1>
<p style="font-family: Georgia">
some text.
</p>
]]>
    </intro>

    <questions xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
        <xi:include href="exam1.xml"/>
    </questions>

</row>
```

**exam1.xml**

```
<question>
            <question_text>Yes; question.</question_text>
            <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
            <distactors>
                <distractor type="1">Strong Argument</distractor>
                <distractor>Weak Argument</distractor>
            </distactors>
        </question>
        <question>
            <question_text>No; one more qurestion.</question_text>
            <image>images/Q1.gif</image>
            <distactors>
                <distractor>Strong Argument</distractor>
                <distractor type="1">Weak Argument</distractor>
            </distactors>
        </question>
```

Comment: Depending on your XML stack supporting it, you could use [XInclude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude) for this task.

Comment: @Boldewyn yeah ive seen this when looking around google. what requirements would i need ?

Comment: Sorry, that has to be answered by someone else (hence a comment, not an answer). I used it years ago with self-written implementations in XSLT and JavaScript, but not in any context, where it had to work on scale.

Comment: @Boldewyn no problem, thank you anyways

Comment: "however my included file dose not seem to load". How exactly are you doing this? What tool/library do you use?

Comment: A "large" XML file these days is perhaps anything over 100Mb. I find it hard to imagine that 7 sections each of 30 questions is more than 100Kb. Which just goes to show that using an adjective like "large" is meaningless and gives no useful information. Always quantify!

Comment: I think your right, im just going to stick with one xml file